# Infinitive recursion when catching an Exception

Tags: java, exception, recursion, java.util.scanner

Here is my code for inputting a student number:
When the user inputs the number in a unexpected format I will ask them to reinput by recursion. But it ends up with an infinitive recursion. Why?

```
private static int inputStudentNumber(){
    System.out.println("Enter the student number:");
    int studentNum;
    try {
        //Scanner in initialized before calling this method
        studentNum = in.nextInt();
        return studentNum;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid input, it can only be integer.");
        return inputStudentNumber();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you have missunderstand recursion

Comment: @JorgeCampos Well, it really *is* recursion, just using the occurrence of an `Exception` as its return condition.  It makes my eye twitch, but...

Comment: Is `in` an _initialized_ Scanner?

Comment: Add in some logging (e.g., `System.out.println()` statements) in the `catch` block.  Find out what kind of `Exception` is being thrown.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Yes "in" is  Scanner from System in

Comment: @Fan there is no base case in your recursion so how you can stop the recursion?!!! it goes forever . I really liked your question

Comment: @asteri LOL to your comment!! Great :)

Comment: This is why you should *never catch `Exception` and assume its safe to continue*... instead, fail and log the full trace for debugging. **If you expect an exception, then be precise on which you catch.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a closer look at the [javadocs for `Scanner.nextInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()):

> This method will throw `InputMismatchException` if the next token cannot be translated into a valid int value as described below. **If the translation is successful**, the scanner advances past the input that matched. *(emphasis added)*

If it's not successful, the scanner isn't advanced. That means that if you try to invoke `nextInt()` again, you'll be trying to get an int from *the same token* as before, and you'll once again get an `InputMismatchException`.

Your code basically says: try to read the next token as an int. If that fails, recurse to try to read the token as an int again. If that fails, recurse to try to read the token as an int again. If that fails... (and so on, until you get a `StackOverflowException` from too much recursion).

If you want to use recursion for this, you should probably use  `next()` to skip to the next token. And only catch `InputMismatchException`, so that you won't also catch `NoSuchElementException` (which won't happen for `System.in`, but is good practice in general -- what if you later decide to read from a file, and that file has reached its end?).

```
} catch(InputMismatchException e) {
    System.out.println("Invalid input, it can only be integer.");
    in.next(); // skip this token
    return inputStudentNumber();
}
```

An even better approach would be to avoid using the exception to control your logic in the first place. To do this, you'd have to know ahead of time whether `nextInt` will succeed. Luckily for you, [`hasNextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt()) lets you do exactly that!

```
private static int inputStudentNumber() {
  System.out.println("Enter the student number:");
  if (in.hasNextInt()) {
    return in.nextInt();
  } else {
    System.out.println("Invalid input, it can only be integer.");
    in.next(); // consume the token
    return inputStudentNumber();
  }
}
```

The advantage here -- besides the general "don't use exceptions for control flow" advice -- is that the base case is super clear. If there's an int ready, that's your base case; if not, you have to advance the scanner and try again.

Comment: @KickButtowski in short, don't use `Scanner` for reading user input. The best bet for this case may be using `Scanner#next` and `Integer.parseInt` instead of `Scanner#nextInt`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza good point but I try to understand the recursion here to improve myself

Comment: @KickButtowski The base case is essentially when `nextInt` returns successfully. It's just that either that will happen the first time (if the user enters a valid string), or it will never happen (because the scanner will never discard the current token and try with the next one).

Comment: @yshavit thank you for your answer but the question is how the op can recover from this exception? is it ok to use inputStudentNumber(); instead of return inputStudentNumber();?

Comment: @KickButtowski there's no base case for this. In fact, this kind of code should be avoided at all cost. This is a great example why is bad to use `catch (Exception e)`. And again, OP should not recover from this exception, instead he/she **must change the design** to avoid this. A change is shown in my previous comment.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza so based on what you say we should not recover from unchecked exception like this case and we should have better desing as you said did I get that right?

Comment: @yshavit thank you but last question that I ask luggi can you tell me if I got that right? what is gonna happen if an user enter int as its next token?

Comment: @KickButtowski I'm not entirely sure what Luiggi's stance is, so I can't say. I think it's fine to catch and handle the `InputMismatchException` (whether by recursing, or continuing a `while` loop, or whatever). I think Luiggi's advice (which I'd agree with) is not to catch just plain `Exception` in a case like this (there are fairly few cases when you should catch `Exception`), but rather to catch the _specific_ error case you want to handle.

Comment: @KickButtowski think about this: have you ever write code to catch `NullPointerException` or any other specific but unexpected `RuntimeException`? Because this is the same case. The best option: change the code to avoid these unexpected `RuntimeException`. If you know you have to handle a specific exception (even for subclasses of `RuntimeException`), then catch and handle them properly. I'm not against not catching `InputMismatchException` in this case, but if this can be avoided, it will be even better.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I just re-read `Scanner`'s docs (I almost never use it) and saw that it has a method `hasNextInt`. So you should use that, instead. If it returns true, return `nextInt`. Otherwise, consume the token and recurse (or loop, either way). I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Luiggi Until Java introduces `TryParse` from C# there's no good way to parse user input into an int.

Comment: @DavidConrad I agree with that. But even for that to work in Java, the language should have to support passing references rather than just values, and then we start an endless discussion...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that if a non-integer is entered as input, then that input is not consumed by the scanner.  So you just keep reading it.

You may want to just read the input as a string and then try to convert it separately.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably that in.nextInt() is throwing an Exception. A code smell that I see is that you use:

```
catch(Exception e) {
    ....
}
```

The best practice here is to only catch the specific Exception you are expecting, so it should be:

```
catch(InputMismatchException e) {
    ....
}
```

If you do this, then whatever `in.nextInt()` is throwing will properly propagate to the top, and you will probably see that in is not initialized or some such problem.

See here for the Exceptions that `nextInt()` can throw.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()

Answer (score -1):

```
try this...

private static int inputStudentNumber(){
    System.out.println("Enter the student number:");
    int studentNum;
    int var = 1;
while(var ==1)´
{
    try{
        studentNum = in.nextInt();
        var=0;
        return studentNum;
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Invalid input, it can only be integer.");
        var=1;
        return inputStudentNumber();
    }
}


}
```